# How to start an app installed from a private npm registry inside another angular2 app

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have created individual apps and published them into a private npm registry. 
I have created a new Angular2 project and installed these apps as dependencies. 
Now when I do npm start the Angular2 app is starting but how do I invoke the other apps which I had installed from the private registry. 
I want all the apps to be working in the same project with displaying corresponding details based on the selection of app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating separate apps. I would suggest to convert them into Angular Module, import them and use them. Otherwise if you can show us your build system for the apps we might be able to help you more.

Comment: So the apps should run independently as well. Just to showcase all the apps at one place (if someone wants to see all the apps at one place instead of visiting individual apps) I am creating this.

Comment: How can I import an angular2 app in another angular2 app? Like importing it in app.module.ts? How does it work?

Comment: @arjun this [link](https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/) might help